# What is the equivalent of ExpressJS for C# / ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ExpressJs, you can quickly set up a web server and have it listen for requests, and register the handlers in-line.

```
    var express = require('express')
    var app = express()

    // respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('hello world')
    })
```

Is it possible to do this in ASP.NET Core, using something like this using middleware?

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Get("/api/v2/", () =>
        {
            return "Hello world";
        });


        //configure more services...
    }
```

Being able to kick off multiple web listeners in the same process would also be handy:

```
using (var server = new WebServer(url))
{
    server.Get("/path", () => { return "Hello world" });
    server.Get("/path2", () => { return "Hello world2" });
    server.RunAsync();
}
```

Would be pretty handy.

Comment: It would only be handy because you are thinking in ExpressJS. In a real application with hundreds to thousands of routes, it is not at all something you'd want.

Comment: This is for a case where there are not thousands of lines of code, i.e. in a test mock web server, the entire server may be 10 lines of code  - there's no point in writing controllers and loading heavy MVC libraries for a tiny tiny app

Comment: What? What heavy libraries? You need to load ASP.NET Core base libraries like it or not. MVC, you may load it if you want to, you don't *have to*.

Comment: Not completely sure if this will help, but I set up a .NET Core library that allows you to use node.js syntax for fun and later realized it was not very practical. Here is the sample code: https://github.com/neville-nazerane/NetCore.NodeJsLike/blob/master/SampleApp/Program.cs

Comment: I had posted an issue online asking about this feature and found out they are working on it for version .NET Core 3.0

Comment: Thanks @NevilleNazerane - this is exactly what I was thinking of! Link to discussion: https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/issues/368

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this. Not a 1-liner like in Express but still could be actually useful to group the different methods for the same route in 1 block.

```
app.Map("/test", (builder) =>
        {
            builder.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Method == "GET", (app2) =>
            {
                app2.Run(async ctx =>
                {
                    await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("I have been reached.");
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I trying to create a project with that allows the node.js exact syntax in .NET Core I realized their respective syntax is meant for the respective environment. I would recommend you take a look into how .NET Core's web API setup where you can check how you can have endpoints while taking advantage of the framework's components.

However, to use the exact code sample you have shown in your second paragraph, you need to define a class like this in your project:

```
public static class AppExtensions
{

    public static IApplicationBuilder Get(this IApplicationBuilder app,
                                            string path, Func<string> run) 
        => app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path == path)
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(run());
                else await next();
            });

}
```